# Compilación proyecto Java (Maven) sobre máquina Vagrant

Tags: java, maven, compilar, vagrant

Estoy intentando compilar un proyecto java grande en un entorno vagrant y al ejecutar `mvn install` se queda colgado y durante horas y no da ni siquiera mensaje de error. ¿A qué puede ser debido que tarde tanto?

¿Al compilar otros repos no me ha dado problema y los POM deben estar bien ya que no hay errores de dependencias..

Gracias!

Comment: Buenas ¿Podrías mostrar los logs para ver si realmente da error o en que proceso se ha quedado atascado? Si usas linux con **mvn clean install | tee log.txt** puedes verlo, con Windows puedes usar el shell de Cygwin.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario! Finalmente se solucionó ya que había problemas con los pom del repo!